# Calculate Polygon Angle of Rotation about the centroid

Tags: python, geometry, angles

I have a collection of polygon geometries in a projected spatial reference.

How can I figure out each polygon's angle of rotation about the centroid?

I am using Python (2 or 3 doesn't matter) to do the calculations.

Comment: Can you add a drawing of your problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please specify how you will determine rotation.

Comment: @Vince that  is what I'm trying to figure out.  I was thinking directional distribution of the vertexes.

Comment: If the shape is a diamond, how can you tell its proper rotation if squares are also permitted?  How do you determine the rotation of a circle? Are all rectangles tall or squat? I'm saying we can't answer this question until you've decided these issues, and have edited the question to include them. After that,  it's just computational geometry.